# libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm using a cross compiled qt 5.4.2 and I getting the following error when I try to build simple QtWidget app (the app is just a window)

```
09:55:42: Running steps for project untitled...
09:55:42: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
09:55:42: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ --sysroot=/home/pf/ssdk-d6cx/host/usr/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt5.4-d6cx/lib -o untitled main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/pf/ssdk-d6cx/host/usr/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/local/qt5.4-d6cx/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/home/pf/ssdk-d6cx/host/usr/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64 -L/usr/local/qt5.4-d6cx/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lpthread 
/home/pf/ssdk-d6cx/host/usr/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/local/qt5.4-d6cx/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled] Error 1
09:55:42: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: d6cx)
When executing step "Make"
09:55:42: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I really don't understand what is going on.

Could be a compatibility problem with some libs on the target OS?

I will appreciate any help that point me to the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command was given for qmake?

Comment: When qmake run it use the following sequence: qmake '/home/pf/D6Cx/test app/untitled/untitled.pro' -r -spec linux-g++

Comment: @Mozfox thank you, you point me to the right direction to find the solution!! Is there any way in which I can give you my positive vote?

Comment: nice to see you got it compiling. :)  May be you can up vote comment.

Comment: I wish but I don't have yet the reputation to vote up... anyway thanks for point me on the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

The real problem was that I was using Qt Creator as IDE to cross compile and it set qmake to use a device different that the one I was cross compiling for.

I mean the original setting for qmake was:

```
qmake '/home/pf/D6Cx/test app/untitled/untitled.pro' -r -spec linux-g++
```

and it should be:

```
qmake '/home/pf/D6Cx/test app/untitled/untitled.pro' -r -spec devices/linux-d6cx-g++
```

whith this last one configuration the app is built correctly!!

The way I use to force qmake to use my specific device was (in Qt Creator):

- go to Projects/Build setting
- in the section Build Steps -> qmake add in Additional arguments:
        -spec devices/linux-d6cx-g++

and that will overwrite the original setting for -spec

Thanks!